# How can I Select all vertices that are outside?

Tags: scripting, vertices, selection-tools

[image]
HI !

I have this wall made by cubes and I am trying, via script, to select vertices of each block, that are outside, like this:

[image]

It´s is possible to make this via python ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this with python because you don't know another way or because you particularly want to use python?

Comment: Because i need to this using python ... @RayMairlot

Comment: sorry, can you explain you "outside" concept.? why that vertex is outside?  can you upload the file please?

Comment: Can use this algorithm by Hulifier and implement it in Python: [Is it possible to scatter points on the outside surface of a group of instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/300094/60486)